# How do I hide all v-text-fields in Vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to hide the text fields in my dialog box pop up to re utilize the same component for Edit & Delete Feature. Basically I am manipulating the header of dialog but for delete feature I want user to only see heading. But I can't find any option to hide all text fields on Vuetify.

**HTML**

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="entryData[item]"
   :label="getLabel(item)"
   :disabled="setDisable(item)">
</v-text-field>
```

**Set Disable function**

```
setDisable (colName) {
  return this.entryState === 'read' || colName.toLowerCase().indexOf('id') !== -1;
},
```

Like disable is there any option for visibility?

Comment: Just use `v-if`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `v-if`

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="entryData[item]"
   :label="getLabel(item)"
   v-if="setDisable(item)">
</v-text-field>
```

or `v-show`

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="entryData[item]"
   :label="getLabel(item)"
   v-show="setDisable(item)">
</v-text-field>
```

the difference between the two is that `v-if` hidden component doesn't get added to your DOM, and the `v-show` component is added, but set to hidden using styles.

On a side note, as mentioned in an earlier question, try to avoid calling functions in the template. this will trigger a re-render on full tree every time, because function responses are not cached. storing these values in a computed is usually the way to go. You can store multiple attributes in the object, and you already have `entryData`, so you can adjust is to include other parameters.

Comment: v-if="msgTitle != 'string' " and its working fine. Thanks you so much!!